# BrowserInstance Doesn't Exist In This Current Context

Tags: c#-4.0

```
  public bool FindText()
    {
        string text = string.Empty;

        IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)browserInstance.Document;
        IHTMLSelectionObject sel = (IHTMLSelectionObject)doc.selection;

        sel.empty(); 
        IHTMLTxtRange rng = (IHTMLTxtRange)sel.createRange();

        if (rng.findText(text, 1000000000, 0))
         {
          rng.select();
          return true;
         } 
      return false;
     }
```

I have used above code to search a text from webBrowser Control and I have used `using mshtml` as reference but I'm facing an error with `browserInstance` as it does not exist in the current context

Comment: sorry first line has gone up

Comment: Using this code i want to count the number of times the text which is present in an Hyperlink ( i mean in Anchor Tag) and loop through all the number of pages in which the particular text is present.